# string concatenation issue during insert statement

Tags: javascript, mysql, string, insert-into

I have a method that constructs an insert query but crashes due to string being malformed. What is that i am missing?

```
saveWorkDocket : function(onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback, options) {            
    var db = Ti.Database.open('xyz');      
    db.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_temp  (tableName, data, id, dateCreated) VALUES ('" + options.tableName + "','" + options.data + "','" + options.workdocketID + "','" + options.dateCreated +'");
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing to close double " in the end of the query and close the function brackets, try this:

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('xyz');      
db.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_temp  (tableName, data, id, dateCreated)   VALUES ('" + options.tableName + "','" + options.data + "','" + options.workdocketID + "','" + options.dateCreated +'")");
```